# How does the table and $freq function work in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I want a function for the mode of a vector. Abhiroop Sarkar's answer to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode) works, but I want to understand why.

Here is the code

```
Mode <- function(x){

y <- data.frame(table(x))
y[y$Freq == max(y$Freq),1]
}
```

1) Wy do we need to put the table in a data frame,

2) in this line

```
 y[y$Freq == max(y$Freq),1]
```

what does the y$Freq do? is frequency a default columns in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we convert a `table` output to  `data.frame`, it creates a two column `data.frame`

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- table(sample(1:5, 100, replace  = TRUE))
y <- data.frame(v1)
y
#  Var1 Freq
#1    1   19
#2    2   24
#3    3   22
#4    4   16
#5    5   19
```

The first column 'Var1' is the `names` of the frequency output from `table` and the 'Freq' is the actual frequency of those `names`

```
y[y$Freq == max(y$Freq), 1]
#[1] 2
#Levels: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Now, we are subsetting the first column 'Var1' based on the `max` value of 'Freq', and it returns a `vector` because of the `drop = TRUE` in `[` when there is a single column

If we want to return a `data.frame` with single, add `drop = FALSE` at the end

```
y[y$Freq == max(y$Freq), 1, drop = FALSE]
#   Var1
#2    2
```

---

Regarding the default name `Freq`, it is created from the `as.data.frame.table` method

```
as.data.frame.table
function (x, row.names = NULL, ..., responseName = "Freq", stringsAsFactors = TRUE, 
    sep = "", base = list(LETTERS)) 
{
    ex <- quote(data.frame(do.call("expand.grid", c(dimnames(provideDimnames(x, 
        sep = sep, base = base)), KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors)), 
        Freq = c(x), row.names = row.names))
    names(ex)[3L] <- responseName
    eval(ex)
}
```

Comment: I understand everything in your answer except for the last sentence. Why does it return a vector? (I get that we are looking at the first column in y based on the max value of Freq)

Comment: @Jess  If you check `?Extract`, the default usage is `x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]` i.e. I I change it to `y[y$Freq == max(y$Freq), 1, drop = FALSE]` it returns a data.frame